# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser: How to read div class=price promo?

Tags: php

I would like to read the price (483.33) from the following HTML code using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser.

I tried to use:

```
find('div.price, div.promo',0)
```

but it doesn't work- Any ideas how to do this?

```
<div class="price promo">
    <div class="status_promo">
      <img src="/images/status_hit.png" alt="status hit cenowy" class="" />
    </div>
    483.33 <span>zł netto</span>
  </div>

<?php foreach ($html->find('div.price, div.promo',0) as $price)
    echo $price->plaintext; ?>
```

Comment: Please provide more code. How did you get the data of price? Is it from database?

Comment: Yes, it's from database, but I don't have an access to this DB. PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser allows to read any data straight from the website HTML. It works with regular <div class="x">, but it doesn't work with <div class="x y">. I would like to read all texts in <div class="price promo"> first, and after that I can remove unecessary "zł netto" (it's simple). More information about PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser you'll find at: https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/

Comment: How about this `$html->find("div[class='price'][class='promo']")` OR `$html->find('div[class=price promo]');`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop the result, since you are already passing an index to the `find` method and it will return the first element or null if not found. Your selector will still match the element you are trying to find, but when an element has multiple classes the proper notation is `div.price.promo`.

```
$price = $html->find('div.price.promo',0);
if ($price) {
    echo $price->plaintext;
}
```

If you have multiple elements that matches the selector, then you do need to loop:

```
foreach ($html->find('div.price.promo') as $price)
   echo $price->plaintext;
```